# Error: PDF file not found

Tags: pdftex, compiling

[image]

After compiling the LaTeX rightly, I try to view the `.pdf` file. 
But it said that

`.pdf file not found`.

I think maybe I need to correct some settings?

I am a beginner

Thank you very much!

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello, world!
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.SE Would you mind posting a Minimal Working Example that will illustrate your problem? Thank's!

Comment: Your question is not well posted. You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see on your screeshot you are using the `LaTeX` engine. Instead of a pdf, this engine provides a dvi-file.
You should use `PDFLaTeX` instead of `LaTeX` (choose from the dropdown list), which should output a proper pdf. See screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your compiler is latex rather than pdflatex. If that's the case, you  will  find a .dvi file in the folder with your document.

To change the default compiler, if this is TeXstudio, try

Options -> Configure -> Build

and set the Default Compiler to PdfLaTeX .

If it's another environment, find out how to set the default compiler there to pdflatex.